# AngularJS $scope dropping value after it is assigned

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am hoping someone can help me understand an annoying problem I am having with $scope in AngularJS. Please see the comments in my code below:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    $http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

            d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property; //Now MyObject is magically undefined.           

        }, 0);
    });
});
```

The call to the WEB API returns a valid object which is assigned to $scope.data. I display an alert to make sure that $scope.data.MyObject.Property exists, which it does. The expected value is displayed.

Now when I try accessing $scope.data.MyObject.Property in the $viewContentLoaded code, the $scope.data.MyObject is no longer in the $scope. The console reports the following:

> HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
>   File: route.html
>   TypeError: Unable to get property 'MyObject' of undefined or null reference
>      at Anonymous function (http://server/script/route.js:43:13)
>      at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:158:234)
>      at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:45:348)
>      at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js:48:275)

Why is $scope dropping the value of $scope.data.MyObject? What makes this problem even more frustrating is if I put an alert(""); in the $viewContentLoaded code, the $scope.data.MyObject value is no longer undefined. What is going on here?

Comment: So maybe `$viewContentLoaded` fires before you're getting response from the server?

Comment: Is there a way I can force $viewContentLoaded to wait for the server's response?

Comment: you can wait until  http promise resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know the timing of how your code get executed.

This is fixed code with some logging:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    console.log(1);

    var promise = $http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        console.log(2);
        alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

            console.log(3);
            // d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property;

            promise.then(function () {
                console.log(4);
                d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property;
            });

        }, 0);
    });
});
```

You may expect the result logs is `1234`, but actually it can be `1324`. In later case, the code in `$viewContentLoaded` is executed *before* the `$http.get` success. So it `$scope.data` is still null.

The solution is using `Promise` (or `$q` in angular world). So that you can wait for the result of `$http.get`. You have guarantee that `4` is always executed *after* `2` (assuming it succeeded).

Comment: Thank you. This has resolved my problem. I need to read up more on  romises. Does an $http.get /post /put /etc return a promise object?

Comment: @Dave Go ahead and change the name `promise` to any other valid js variable name it will just work fine. In simple words, It's like the `$http.get` is taken in a variable and the service will execute only when `variable_name.then()` is called.

Comment: @Dave You can read the documentation for [`$http#get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get), it returns a `HttpPromise` which is a Promise object

Answer (score 0):

Well, this behavior is because JavaScript code is get executed `async`. so better to include that code once promise is resolved.

```
$http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

            d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property; //Now MyObject is magically undefined.           

        }, 0);
    }).error(function (data) {
    alert(data);
    });

});
```

This will work :)

Cheers!

Comment: this will not work if `$viewContentLoaded` is fired _before_ `$http` success

Answer (score 0):

The $http request is ansynchronous. It may not complete before your $viewContentLoaded event is fired. ( I guess this event fires after DOM is loaded and does not wait for http requests to complete, I may be wrong).
Why not do something like this:

```
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;

    $http.get("http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + $scope.id).success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        alert($scope.data.MyObject.Property); //displays the expected value. - Not Undefined or null
        $timeout(function () {
            var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

            d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property; //Now MyObject is magically undefined.           

        }, 0);
    }).error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {

    });
```

Comment: this may cause error if `$http.get` resolved before `$viewContentLoaded`. which `iframe` may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since http get is async function. you have to use promises to wait until http get fetches the result.
you can do this by following code.
make a service.

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {

var getData = function(id) {

    // Angular $http() and then() both return promises themselves 
    return $http({method:"GET", url:"http://server/api/Blah/GetData/" + id}).then(function(result){

        // What we return here is the data that will be accessible 
        // to us after the promise resolves
        return result.data; //or may be return result only.
    });
    };
     return { getData: getData };
      });
```

in your controller

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout,myService) {
$scope.id = $routeParams.id;
var Data=myService.getData($scope.id);
   Data.then(function(result){
    $scope.data.MyObject.Property=result;//or result.data may be
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        var d = document.getElementById("iframe");

        d.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = $scope.data.MyObject.Property; //Now MyObject is magically undefined.           

    }, 0);
});

   });
```

Answer (score -2):

To begin with, the declaration of the controller is missing elements. It should be:

```
app.controller('MyController', ["$scope" , "$routeParams" , "$http" , function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $timeout) {...
```

Check Dependency Injection in Angular's docs.

Try this and, if still not working, update your question with the new code and some loggings.

Comment: this is not necessary. most people are using `ng-annotate` or something similar. The error OP is facing also doesn't match to the behaviour of invalid dependencies.

Comment: Up to you to try it.

Comment: This is for minification of angular file and not for dependency injection.